# How do I get RavenDB to save Periodic Backups to Amazon Glacier?

Tags: ravendb, amazon-glacier

I would like to use RavenDB's Periodic Backup feature. Specifically I want to save to my Amazon Glacier vault.

My current setup is shown below. Raven is not logging any alerts or exceptions but no files are appearing in the vault. I have waited 24 hrs just in case it takes a while to show up.

**Amazon Setup**
[image]

**RavenDB Setup**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the 2.0 version of the studio that doesn't setup periodic backup properly. This will be addressed in the next release, expected this week.